Horowitz Third Edition Figure 2.10 Whys
Referring to the quoted section from the book, there are two why's for the circuit in Figure 2.10 B.

First one asks why R3 contributes only 0.6 mA of current to Q2 collector.
Then in the footer it asks why if R3 is 100 ohms then Q3 shuts off.

My understanding:

The base of Q3 is 0.6 V down than the 15 V supply because of the Q3 emitter to base diode drop. This is what appears across R3 which is 1K ohms, and so we get 0.6/1000=0.6 mA
Note that in reality the transistors which I had (2N3904 & 2N3906) with me the emitter to base diode voltage drop was at 0.7 V when conducting 3.34 mA, and 0.4 V when shut off. This I understand to be normal diode behaviour from an experiment suggested in the book/lab manual.

Now if R3 is reduced to 100 then this “can” become 6 mA. It does not become so because then the drop on R2 exceeds 15 V: 6 mA x 3.3 kΩ = 19.8 V. Instead, it supplies all of the current which can produce a voltage drop of 14.4 V over R2, which is 14.4/3.3k = 4.36 mA.
Since R3 is supplying all of the current then Q3 base is somehow “overridden” to 0 mA and so Q3 shuts off.


So, in summary, Q2 collector needs 4.36 mA, which can come from R3 plus Q3 base. Whatever R3 can supply Q3 base then compensates for the remaining. This is the part which I am not sure of. I do not understand the intuitive physics behind this. Can anyone please help me out here?
From The Art of Electronics (3rd edition), section 2.2.2 Switching circuit examples:

An awkwardness of this circuit is the need to hold the
input at +15 V to turn off the switch; it would be much
better to use a lower control voltage, for example, +3 V and
ground, commonly available in digital logic that we’ll be
seeing in Chapters 10–15. Figure 2.10B shows how to do
that: npn switch Q2 accepts the “logic-level” input of 0 V or +3 V, pulling its collector load to ground accordingly.
When Q2 is cut off, R3 holds Q3 off; when Q2 is saturated (by a +3 V input), R2 sinks base current from Q3 to bring it
into saturation.
The “divider” formed by R2R3 may be confusing: R3’s job is to keep Q3 off when Q2 is off; and when Q2 pulls
its collector low, most of its collector current comes from
Q3’s base (because only ∼0.6 mA of the 4.4 mA collector
current comes from R3 – make sure you understand why).
That is, R3 does not have much effect on Q3’s saturation.
Another way to say it is that the divider would sit at about
+11.6 V (rather than +14.4 V), were it not for Q3’s base–emitter diode, which consequently gets most of Q2’s col-
lector current. In any case, the value of R3 is not critical and could be made larger; the tradeoff is slower turn-off of
Q3, owing to capacitive effects.12

Figure 12.10. Switching the high side of a load returned to ground.

12 But don’t make it too small: Q3 would not switch at all if R3 were
reduced to 100 Ω (why?). We were surprised to see this basic error in
an instrument, the rest of which displayed circuit design of the highest sophistication.


Q3's base-emitter junction isn't "overridden", it simply isn't given enough forward voltage to start conducting if R3 is too low.

Related question: Why would the transistor not switch?

Related question: PNP circuit - The Art of Electronics

Related question: The Art of Electronics, figure 2.10B

Related question: Switching the high side of a load - The Art of Electronics

Just to put things into the schematic editor here, find the following as Figure 2.10B:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

"because only \$\approx 0.6\: \text{mA}\$ of the \$4.4\:\text{mA}\$ collector current comes from \$R_3\$ -- make sure you understand why"

When looking at a circuit like this, your eye should be drawn to \$Q_3\$ and recognize it as a switch-mode use and not an analog-mode. This means \$Q_3\$ will be operated saturated, forcing the collector to act like a voltage source and to be brought very close to its emitter voltage, which is \$+15\:\text{V}\$. So expect the collector to be about \$+14.8\:\text{V}\$, as seen by the load.
Also, \$\beta_3\$ will be very low in such cases. Likely, \$\beta_3\lt 20\$. And perhaps for heavier loads perhaps as bad as \$\beta\lt 5\$.
This would be the case, perhaps, for a 2N3055:

So the next thought you have should be, "What's the load current and what kind of transistor must be used for \$Q_3\$?" The reason is that for larger currents the bipolar will have lower values for \$\beta\$, such as \$\beta=5\$, than would be the case for smaller currents, where these different bipolars could reasonably be expected to exhibit \$\beta=10\$ and \$\beta=20\$, when saturated.
Your eye should now be drawn to \$Q_2\$, which is also being used as a switch-mode device. Again, in saturation. Again, the same ideas about the collector behavior and its proximity to its emitter (which is at ground.) But in this case, it's much less likely that \$Q_2\$ will be carrying a high load current -- just the base current for \$Q_3\$, instead -- so this means that the expected \$\beta_2\$ can be closer to \$\beta_2=10\$ and \$\beta_2=20\$, when saturated.
At this point, you should have realized that the base of \$Q_3\$, when activated as a switch, will be somewhere between \$+14.4\:\text{V}\$ and \$+14.1\:\text{V}\$. (Where exactly will depend on details of \$Q_3\$ and how it is operated by this circuit.) And also, that \$Q_2\$'s collector will be close to ground. Perhaps \$\le +200\:\text{mV}\$. This means that there will be a difference between the base of \$Q_3\$ and the collector of \$Q_2\$ of about \$14\:\text{V}\$. This is something else that should be now entering your mind, when reading this circuit.
So, if you know the load's requirements as \$I_{_\text{LOAD}}\$, then it follows that \$R_2=\beta_3\,\cdot\frac{14\:\text{V}}{I_{_\text{LOAD}}}\$. Their value of \$R_2=3.3\:\text{k}\Omega\$ means a \$Q_2\$ collector current of about \$\frac{14\:\text{V}}{3.3\:\text{k}\Omega}\approx 4.3\:\text{mA}\$. This is about what the textbook says.
This is low enough that we can say that \$Q_3\$ is not a 2N3055.
At this point it is time to reflect.
This circuit will support \$I_{_\text{LOAD}}\le 100\:\text{mA}\$. This means that \$Q_3\$ is smaller, not larger. So \$\beta_3\ge 20\$. Likely, anyway.
From the above, we can also expect that \$\beta_2\ge 20\$, as well. This means that that the base current for \$Q_2\$ will be \$\le 250\:\mu\text{A}\$. From this, we can work out that \$R_1\approx \frac{3.3\:\text{V}-650\:\text{mV}}{250\:\mu\text{A}}\approx 10\:\text{k}\Omega\$. Take note that this matches their selection quite closely!
This leaves \$R_3\$. Here, the "rule of thumb" (my apologies to women and the historical origins of that phrase) would be to use about 10% of the \$4.3\:\text{mA}\$ for this pull-up. So we'd guess at \$R_3\approx\frac{800\:\text{mV}}{430\:\mu\text{A}}=1.86\:\text{k}\Omega\$. Making this a little stiffer would mean we could accept \$R_3\approx 1\:\text{k}\Omega\$.
At this point, we've decided to agree with the authors. And we know a lot more about the range of the allowable load, now.
What happens if \$R_3=100\:\Omega\$?? Well, the current in \$R_3\$ will increase by about a factor of 10. Instead of about \$430\:\mu\text{A}\$, it will move towards about \$4.3\:\text{mA}\$. Which is all of our allocated base current for \$Q_3\$.
So that is why lowering \$R_3=100\:\Omega\$ is a problem. It would siphon away the necessary base current for \$Q_3\$ when that low.
Hopefully, this mental walk through the circuit helps.

Another way to analyze it is to convert the combination of R2 and R3 to their Thévenin equivalent in both cases.
Ignoring the VCE(sat) of Q2, and using the emitter of Q3 as the reference point:

The combination of 3.3 kΩ and 1.0 kΩ has a Thévenin equivalent of
$$V_{th} = -15 V\frac{1 k\Omega}{1 k\Omega + 3.3 k\Omega} = -3.488 V$$
and
$$R_{th} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{1 k\Omega}+\frac{1}{3.3 k\Omega}} = 767 \Omega$$
which can easily drive
$$\frac{3.488 V - 0.7 V}{767 \Omega} = 3.6 mA$$
into the base of Q3.
The combination of 3.3 kΩ and 100 Ω has a Thévenin equivalent of
$$V_{th} = -15 V\frac{100 \Omega}{100 \Omega + 3.3 k\Omega} = -0.441 V$$
and
$$R_{th} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{100 \Omega}+\frac{1}{3.3 k\Omega}} = 97 \Omega$$
which isn't enough voltage to drive any current at all into Q3.


Here's my reasoning, see if it agrees with yours:
Q3's base-emitter junction is really just a silicon diode. It tends to become very, very conductive as the voltage across it approaches 0.6V or so. You can see this behaviour when you plot the I-V curve for a diode, and a B-E junction:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
As I increase current \$I_1\$ through the diode, and (a copy) \$I_2\$ through the transistor's B-E junction, from zero to 3mA, while measuring the voltage across each, it's clear that voltage flattens out to a plateau of about 0.6V:

It would take a great deal more current than 1mA to make the voltage across those elements significantly exceed 0.6V, and they effectively "clamp" that voltage to a maximum of 0.6V or so.
With R3 connected directly in parallel with that base-emitter junction, the voltage across R3 will not exceed 0.6V either. By Ohm's law, the current through R3 will reach a maximum near:
$$ I_{R3} = \frac{V_{R3}}{R_3} = \frac{0.6V}{1k\Omega} = 0.6mA $$
For the second "why", the base-emitter junction does impose a maximum on the voltage across R3, but not a minimum. Remembering that R3 and R2 form a potential divider, when Q2 is switched on, completely saturated, the bottom of that divider chain is effectively grounded:

simulate this circuit
If \$R_3=100\Omega\$, then the voltage across it would be:
$$ V_{R3} = 15V \times \frac{R_3}{R_2+R_3}=15 \times \frac{100}{3300+100} = 441mV $$
Remember that's the voltage across Q3's base-emitter junction, and it's not enough to switch that transistor on.

Basic idea
Somewhat unexpectedly surprising, we can formulate it this way: despite the fact that a transistor consumes base current, we can reliably control it only by voltage produced by a real voltage source with some internal resistance.
A voltage divider is a practical example of such a source. That is why the circuit in the H&H book uses two resistors (R2 and R3) connected in series.
How to explore it
So, the part of the circuit that interests us is a voltage divider with a nonlinear load (the base-emitter junction of the transistor). To gain an intuitive understanding of what happens in this circuit, we can simulate the nonlinear load with a dynamic resistor having two resistance values depending on the circuit's state. The transistor Q1 can be simulated with an SPST switch SW with two resistance values - RQ1 = 100 Ω when on and RQ1 = 1 MΩ when off.
Let's now explore the circuit's operation in several steps using CircuitLab.
Voltage divider unloaded
SW ON (RQ1 = 100 Ω): First, let's examine the voltage divider without a load (Q2's base-emitter junction). As we will see below, the transistor Q2 is on (saturated) when the input voltage Vbe = 861.7 mV (R2 = 16 kΩ).

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
But to be sure, we oversaturate it by setting a voltage of 3.3 V at no load (R2 = 3.435 kΩ).

simulate this circuit
SW OFF (RQ1 = 1 MΩ): Also, Q2 is cut off when Vbe = 434mV (R3 = 30 kΩ)...

simulate this circuit
... but to be sure, we apply a much lower voltage of 15 mV (R3 = 1 kΩ).

simulate this circuit
Real transistor circuit
Now, let's connect the input of transistor Q2 to the output of the voltage divider and examine the voltages and currents in the circuit by hovering the mouse over its elements.
SW ON: We can imagine the base-emitter junction of Q1 as a "static" resistor with low resistance Rbe = Vbe/Ib = 274.6 Ω.

simulate this circuit
SW OFF: Now, the static Rbe resistance is very high, and we can simply assume it is 1 MΩ.

simulate this circuit
Equivalent resistor circuit
Now, we can replace the transistor with the calculated values of the static resistances from the schematics above...
SW ON: ... when it is on. As you can see, resistor R3 is shunted by the low-resistance Rbe and the current is determined exclusively by R2.

simulate this circuit
SW OFF: Now the high-resistance Rbe is shunted by R3 and the current is determined exclusively by the high-resistance RQ1.

simulate this circuit
Equivalent circuit visualized
For convenience, we can visualize the currents flowing through the resistors (including Rbe) by replacing them with ammeters with the same resistance. The voltage Vbe we measure with an "ideal" voltmeter.
SW ON: R2 (3.435 kΩ) and RQ1 (100 Ω) constitute the resistance Rb (3.535 kΩ) of the ammeter.

simulate this circuit
SW OFF: Now Rb is simply RQ1 = 1 MΩ.

simulate this circuit
